# How can i optimize my solution not to exceed time limit on my task?

Tags: python, optimization

I wrote a program that receives name from user checks if it is already taken in database and if it's not prints "OK". If name is taken program must make new name using old name + number. I keep getting "time limit exceed" error but i don't know what's wrong. I am new to programming so do not judge me strictly.
Here is my code:

```
n = int(input())
names = []
def CheckDB(name):
    for i in names:
        if i == name:
            return(True)
    return(False)
def MakeNewName(name, number):
    while CheckDB(name+str(number)):
        number+=1
    newName = name+str(number)
    names.append(newName)
    return(newName)
def CreateNewUser(name):
    if CheckDB(name):
        return(MakeNewName(name,  1))
    names.append(name)
    return("OK")
for i in range (n):
    name = input()
    print(CreateNewUser(name))
```

Input looks like this:

```
100000
hgtyyvplfrlcr
dcvexvhgtyyvplfrlcryws
hmidcvexvhgtyyvplfrlcryw
vexvhgtyyv
idcvexvhgtyyv
vhgt
midcvexvhgtyyvplfrlcry
yv
lfrl
gtyyvplfrlcryw
xvhgtyyvplfrlcryws
yv
midcvexvhgtyyvplfrlcry
hmidcve
vexvhgtyyv
dcvexvhgtyy
midcvexvhgty
id
xvhgtyyvpl
midcvexvhgtyyvplfrlc
idcvexvhgtyyvplfr
idcvexvhgtyyvplfrl
dcvexvhgtyyv
midcv
midcvexvhgt
idcvexvhgtyyvplfrlcr
midcvexvhgtyy
yvplfrlcryw
midcvexv
l
dcvexvhgtyy
dcv
midcvexvhgtyyvplfrlc
vexvhgtyyvplfrlcry 
yvpl
hmidcvexvhgtyyvplfr
```

And so on
p.s. sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Python has no built-in 'time limit exceeded' error and your code doesn't show any time limit or what is being timed, so it's hard to say exactly what is going on, but note that time taken by naive linear search of a list grows linearly with the length of the list, and you're doing it many times for names already taken. If you instead use a set to store names, you can check if a name is taken using `name in names` and this will always take a constant amount of time no matter how large your 'database' grows.

Keep in mind this wouldn't matter if you were using an actual database, as the underlying database engine would handle efficiently indexing primary key columns for you.